# Optimize a redis appendonly file

Tags: redis

I have a `appendonly.aof` file that's grown too large (1.5gb, and 29,558,054 lines).

When I try and load redis it hangs on "Loading data into memory" for what seems like all day (still hasn't finished).

Is there anything I can do to optimize this file as it likely contains many duplicate transactions (like deleting the same record).

Or anything I can do to see progress to know if i'm waiting for nothing or how long it will take before I try and restore an older backup?

Answer (score 1):

With redis 4+ you can use mixed format for optimizing appendonly by setting `aof-use-rdb-preamble` to yes.

With this setting in place redis dumps the data in RDB format to AOF file with every `BGAOFREWRITE` call, which you can verify by aof files contents which starts with REDIS keyword.

Upon restarts with this REDIS keyword in aof file along with this `aof-use-rdb-preamble`, redis will load the RDB followed by aof contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your Redis server based on [this AOF](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-4-keeping-data-safe-and-ensuring-performance/4-1-persistence-options/4-1-3-rewritingcompacting-append-only-files/)

And if you are using docker you should be careful with [how frequently your container is being restarted](https://github.com/sourcegraph/sourcegraph/issues/3300)